# Whoosh MemoryError when opening Searcher of a big index

Tags: python, memory, whoosh

I have Whoosh index of size 33 GB. It contains 17 segments of size ranging from 30 MB to 8 GB.

Trying to get the Searcher object

```
from whoosh import index

ix = index.open_dir(ix_folder)
with ix.searcher() as searcher:
    pass
```

raises a Memory Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
    with ix.searcher() as searcher:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python3\lib\site-packages\whoosh\index.py", line 318, in searcher
    return Searcher(self.reader(), fromindex=self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python3\lib\site-packages\whoosh\index.py", line 548, in reader
    info.generation, reuse=reuse)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python3\lib\site-packages\whoosh\index.py", line 535, in _reader
    readers = [segreader(segment) for segment in segments]
  File "C:\Program Files\Python3\lib\site-packages\whoosh\index.py", line 535, in <listcomp>
    readers = [segreader(segment) for segment in segments]
  File "C:\Program Files\Python3\lib\site-packages\whoosh\index.py", line 524, in segreader
    generation=generation)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python3\lib\site-packages\whoosh\reading.py", line 620, in __init__
    self._terms = self._codec.terms_reader(self._storage, segment)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python3\lib\site-packages\whoosh\codec\whoosh3.py", line 122, in terms_reader
    postfile = segment.open_file(storage, self.POSTS_EXT)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python3\lib\site-packages\whoosh\codec\base.py", line 556, in open_file
    return storage.open_file(fname, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python3\lib\site-packages\whoosh\filedb\filestore.py", line 333, in open_file
    return self.a.open_file(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python3\lib\site-packages\whoosh\filedb\compound.py", line 121, in open_file
    f = BufferFile(buf, name=name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python3\lib\site-packages\whoosh\filedb\structfile.py", line 357, in __init__
    self.file = BytesIO(buf)
MemoryError
```

Sometimes Whoosh consumes 500 MB of memory, another time - all available memory (about 4 GB). Occasionally Whoosh works, but in a minute it can stop to work no matter how much memory it ate, now matter what computer I use.

Hence the question: how to fix Memory Error for large indexes? I tried to recreate the index which did't help. Any way to restrict memory consumption, to clear cache somehow, etc? Creating one big segment is not a way out.

Here is the index structure:

```
def create_index(ix_folder):
    schema = Schema(numid=ID(stored=True, unique=True),
                    date1=DATETIME(),
                    date2=DATETIME(),
                    days=NUMERIC(stored=True),
                    title=TEXT(stored=True, phrase=True, field_boost=1.15),
                    abstract=TEXT(phrase=True),
                    article_text=TEXT(phrase=True),
                    numc=NUMERIC(stored=True),
                    numq=NUMERIC(stored=True),
                    types=ID(),
                    )
    index.create_in(ix_folder, schema)
```

Comment: I get this too, and the total index size is only 307 MB on disk. Must be a leak somewhere.

Comment: In [this issue](https://bitbucket.org/mchaput/whoosh/issues/485/whoosh-raises-memoryerror-if-importing) it appears that order of seemingly unrelated imports can have an effect.

Comment: @OrangeDog, I created this issue in bitbucket as I thought it might help. However, now I get the error even without additional imports. You are probably right about the leak. Matt has been working on nextgen branch, but it is still raw and buggy.

Comment: What version of Whoosh was the index created with? Before 2.5 it would also save and load field caches, which could be very big.

Comment: The index was created in Whoosh 2.7.4

Comment: My issue turned out to be because whoosh allocated a set of all the deleted doc ids, for every leaf node in the query matcher, for every segment. For some unknown reason this memory was never released (although the set objects themselves were).

Answer (score 1):

This can be due to Whoosh's default use of mmap'ed segment reading. If the segment is too big for available memory, Whoosh throws a MemoryError when creating the BytesIO for the buffer. Fortunately, Whoosh includes a way to disable mmap.

#### Quick Fix

The simple solution is to replace the storage used by whoosh with one that doesn't use mmap:

```py
from whoosh.filedb.filestore import FileStorage
from whoosh.index import EmptyIndexError

storage = FileStorage(ix_folder, supports_mmap=False)
# schema as per the schema you posted in the question.
try:
  index = storage.open_index(schema)
except EmptyIndexError:
  index = storage.create_index(schema)
```

#### Better Fix

Using mmap is faster when you can. You might want to look at the size of your index on disk and your available memory and decide on a ratio below which to disable mmap. It would be nice if Whoosh did this itself or retried MemoryErrors without mmap, but alas with v2 we have to do this ourselves.

#### Haystack

For Haystack users like me, I do this step in a custom backend.setup() method that inherits from `haystack.backends.whoosh_backend.WhooshSearchBackend`